# Style to selected in dropdown list

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style the selected option in a dropdown list. I've found a way to change the background colour but I need to change the text colour. I really could do with doing by css.

```
nav select{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    appearance: none;
    background: #66822e url(../images/arrow.png) no-repeat right top;
    color: #ffffff; 
    font-size: 100%;
    height: 21px;
    border: 0;
}

nav option:checked, nav option:hover {
    color: #910000 !important;
    background: #d1e40a repeat url("data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQ...");
}
```

Is there a way to get the selected text to show in a shade of red? I'm testing in Firefox. Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/urbbjrbg/

Comment: If you make a running snippet it is easier for us to answer.

Comment: This CSS seems to work in Chrome, the text of the selected item is red.

Comment: The default text was red in Chrome for me and the shade of green I wanted. By all the other options were the default style for me.

The options were the green but with the text still white in Firefox.

Comment: Not a way to present the code.. please do place in fiddle..

Comment: Okay vignesh. I've updated the question to include a fiddle.